# How to push my git svn config to another repository?

Tags: git, svn, push, config

I've set up a git project based on a svn project, everything works fine.

Now I would like my Jenkins to make an automated "git svn dcommit" every time the master branch changes.

But the svn configuration is stored in .git/config and some refs in .git/svn/refs and I if push my changes, the jenkins repository is not aware of the svn config and refs.

How I deploy this configs?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are Jenkins and your SVN repository on the same server?

Comment: No, the SVN repository is on a remote server

Answer (score 0):

If your Subversion and Git repositories resided on the same machine, then you may use [SubGit](http://subgit.com/) to join them. Then when you push to the Git repository, Subversion repository will automatically pick your commit.

Comment: That would be a good idea, unfortunately the subversion is on a remote server. If i could just get the .git/config settings and the .git/svn to be pushed to the other git repositories I could solve my problem.